# Correct Way to Transfer Props to State (if needed) React & Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have created a Create-React-App react app & Redux.

I am using connect to map my userReducer to state (via mapStateToPrope) ie:

```
function mapStateToProps({ userProfile }) {
return { userProfile: userProfile ? userProfile : null };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, fetchUserProfile)(Profile);
```

and I have an input which I have binded the UserProfile Firstname to:

```
render(){
   return (
    <div>
       <input type="text" value={this.props.userProfile.firstName} />
   </div>
 ) 
}
```

This issue is now that I have it binded to the props, I am unable to change it, If I type in the input it wont change the text inside the input..

If I add a onChange={updateValue}  method, and try and update the prop it wont work as a component can not update its own props.

So that leaves Transfering the props to state.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { FirstName : this.props.userProfile.firstName }
}
```

is this the recommended way to get an initial value from props?

Comment: Why don't you use the store (redux) if you are using redux already?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to use a controlled input without providing information about updating the state.

If you just want to provide an initial state, you could use the `defaultValue` property of input fields.

```
<input defaultValue={this.props.value} />
```

With this you could easily change the input value, without writing overhead.

However, if you want to update your component, you should use the component state (like you did in your onChange example) or you use the redux state, if you want to provide the input value to more components than your input component.

```
const Component = ({ firstname, updateFirstname }) => (
  <input
    onChange={updateFirstname}
    value={firstname}
  />
);

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  firstname: state.profile.firstname,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  updateFirstname: e => dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_FIRSTNAME', firstname: e.target.value }),
});

connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Component);
```

Comment: this would work.. I just need to set the initial value, allow the user to change the value, and then if they click SAVE It needs to shoot the entire userprofile to the action to update via AJAX... so with this method as its not binded I would need to somehow get the new values on save click...

Comment: Ok, if you just want to post the state on form submission, you could write an onSubmit handler into your form, posting the FormData object. But maybe I would take the component state path, because you don't have to deal with FormData and you can use the state directly as your JSON for the AJAX request. :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to have a change take place managed in either local state or redux, you want to call the function onChange as follows

```
onChange={(e) => this.updateField('fieldName',e.target.value,e)}
```

The value field would be and would always be updated when the props (or state are updated)

```
value={this.props.fieldName}
```

or

```
value={this.state.fieldName}
```

You onChange function would either call setState({fieldName: value}) to set local state or dispatch to redux to update the Store which is turn would update the local state via your mapStateToProps function.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong in doing that for a controlled component. But one mistake you made is there is no `this.props` in the constructor. You're passing props directly to the constructor using the `props` variable. So the code will be

```
this.state = {
  FirstName: props.userProfile.firstName
};
```

But if you want the value from the store to be updated on the component later on then do declare `componentWillReceiveProps()` and set the state value there also so that the changes in store are captured here.